# How to hide the Back Button (More) of a View inside TabView

Tags: swiftui

I have a TabView with many items and I would like to hide the back button (<More) from the last one.

```
struct ExperimentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            AView(label: "1")
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Tab1", systemImage: "list.dash")
                }

            AView(label: "2")
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Tab2", systemImage: "square.and.pencil")
                }

            AView(label: "3")
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Tab3", systemImage: "pencil.slash")
                }

            AView(label: "4")
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Tab4", systemImage: "scribble")
                }

            AView(label: "5")
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Tab5", systemImage: "pencil.tip")
                }

            AView(label: "6")
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Tab6", systemImage: "pencil.and.outline")
                }
        }
    }
}

struct AView: View {
    var label: String

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Text(label)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

I tried:

```
AView(label: "6")
   .navigationBarTitle("")
   .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
   .tabItem {
      Label("Tab6", systemImage: "pencil.and.outline")
   }
```

but it did't help.

Comment: As far as I know, this isn't possible -- if you have too many tabs to display, this system will render that "More" button

Comment: I think so too, but I hoped that someone more expert than me could provide a trick.